# link_to :method and confirm: not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

No matter how many solutions I've tried, nothing is working. Confirm popup will not generate, and it will ONLY send a GET every time.

I've tried both of these formats, both do the same thing (nothing)

```
%li= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: "delete", data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}
%li= link_to 'Log out2', {controller: "users/sessions", action: "destroy"}, confirm: "Are you sure?"
```

Here is the HTML generated:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Log out</a>
```

***application.js***

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

***application.html.haml***

```
= stylesheet_link_tag    "application"
    = javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr"
    = javascript_include_tag "application" 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
```

Comment: When you run 'rake routes', is "destroy_user_session" listed with a verb of "DELETE"?

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "sure"} %>
```

You should not put the delete in quotes .

Comment: I had it that way first and still got the same result. I just put it in quotes to try something else.